# Return a object from two nested queries using promises with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nested

I need to build a object from the result of two queries but i'm getting undefined. From each object returned at 1st query, I need to set a list with 2nd query. But i getting difficult working with promises when I need to do some implementation nested with the result of chaining queries.

Both queries are working and returning the correct values.

My problem here are involving some logic and "not knowing how to work with javascript and promises" issues.

I appreciate any tips

my code:

```
 var aFunction = function(){

      //this query return a list of A objects

      return myDAO.getADataList()
        .then(function(aDataList){

          aDataList.forEach(function(aData){

            //this query return a list of B objects to each A object

            myDAO.getBdataFromA(aData.id)
              .then(function(bDataList){

                //here i want to return a object with both values

                return {
                  aValue: aData,
                  list : bDataList
                }
              })
          })
        });
      }

        aFunction()
          .then(function(data){
            //here data is undefined
            console.log(data);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise.all:

```
return myDAO.getADataList()
.then(function(aDataList){
  return Promise.all(
    aDataList.map(function (aData) {
      //this query return a list of B objects to each A object
      return myDAO.getBdataFromA(aData.id)
        .then(function (bDataList) {
          //here i want to return a object with both values
          return {
            aValue: aData,
            list: bDataList
          }
        })
    })
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not return anything at the second promise that's why you get undefined.

```
  .then(function(aDataList){
    aDataList.forEach(function(aData){
      myDAO.getBdataFromA(aData.id)
```

To solve this you need to return value by aggregating result from `myDAO.getBdataFromA`. You can use `Array.map` and `Promise.all` to do that.

```
a var aFunction = function(){
//this query return a list of A objects
return myDAO.getADataList()
  .then(function(aDataList){
    var getaDataListPromises = aDataList.map(myDAO.getBdataFromA(aData.id)
    .then(function(bDataList){
      //here i want to return a object with both values
      return {
        aValue: aData,
        list : bDataList
      }
    }));
    return Promise.all(getaDataListPromises);
  });
}
```